# World and societies after the nuclear war

Tags: post-apocalypse

Im interested in your answers or existing books and films on the topic on how would a society function assuming a large scale nuclear war, but no nuclear winter. Real world, so no magic or mutants. And not as extreme as Mad Max, so a society and communication still work at least to some extend. And about half of mankind survived.

Im mostly interested about how would an ordinary person live in such a world, what jobs would be available, what food will be in shops, if shops would remain at all. What technological level would mankind be able to maintain. What percentage of casualties will be due to hunger, radiation, violence and deseases. How much would a world restore in a year and in a decade.

Im not that interested in heroic stories, secret laboratories, politics, war itself, as it cant be changed by average people anyway. It is all important in a sense that it will affect the everyday life of people, but it shouldnt be the center point, unless its effect truly overshadows everything else.

Comment: In germany, we experienced the "war for toilet paper" less than two years ago, because apparently some people thought it might become scarce. This leads me to assume that shortly after the outbreak of a war on such a scale, the civil war for resources (and, strangely, luxury goods) might well cause even more casualties than the 'official' war does.

Comment: Seems like it would depend upon what kind of society prevailed in the war. If most of the casualties were located in the capitals of authoritarian regimes (including many leaders), the emerging society would look different than if most of the casualties were among free peoples.

Comment: @user535733 im interested in europe countries. almost all people here are free

Comment: You are welcome to explore [After the End](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AfterTheEnd) and [Scavenger World](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ScavengerWorld) (TV Tropes warning).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question for a lot of reasons. (a) You're allowed to ask only one question. (b) This is an off-topic [high concept question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4868/40609). (c) Stack exchange is not a discussion forum. (d) The [help/on-topic] states questions "Must be specific and answerable." This is neither without writing your story for you.

Comment: Hi @SurprisedSeagull, try to please focus on one problem as a time. It won't be possible to have a single answer to the many questions in here. For example, make this about what jobs would be created; then another question about casualties, etc. VTC until edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A MORE RURAL WORLD**

If half the population survived the war, I don't expect society to entirely collapse, unless the land becomes too radioactive to live in - but if it was, half the population would not have survived, and there would have been a nuclear winter.

I assume that the bombs mainly targeted major cities and military installations. More than half the world's population lives in cities, so the rural population and infrastructure should be left mainly untouched by the major blasts. Rural areas are where food is produced, and while the food is likely to be contaminated by radioactive fallout, it should remain edible. Trees and wildlife around Chernobyl are doing fine. Instances of cancer and misshapen children will likely be high, but enough will likely survive to keep the rural society going much as it did a hundred years ago. Wind farms and solar parks could still provide electricity for important purposes, and some crops can be converted to biodiesel or bioethanol for fuel - and draft animals will have a comeback.

Ham radios could still be operated to maintain contact between communities, and there could even be some kind of postal service using horses, like the pony express, or using gliders.

This relatively peaceful post-holocaust society is not meant to diminish the dangers of nuclear war. 3 or 4 billion people will die in the initial holocaust, and perhaps a billion more from radiation-related causes over the following decades - and radiation poisoning and harmful mutations will be a condition of life for generations, shortening average lifespans to perhaps 50 years or less. But I doubt that violent gangs will be a major problem. We can compare to the aftermath of the Black Death in Europe, where the survivors lived quite peaceful lives, with more space and food per citizen. Farm workers even had it very well for a while, since they were in high demand and could just walk away from lords that didn't treat them well.

Answer (score 0):

The [book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_the_Beach_(novel)) and [movie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_the_Beach_(1959_film)) of *On the Beach* is an example of what happens when nuclear war goes too far: no-one survives.

The cause of the lethal radiation levels were the use of [cobalt bombs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cobalt_bomb).

Comment: I cant imagine a realistic scenario that would result in 90% population reduction. Let alone 99% or even more... each additional order of magnitude population reduction would require an order of magnitude more destructive force. Afaik cobalt bombs arent in use today

Comment: This answer really seems like a link only answer.

Comment: @Topcode im fine with link only answers, if it would be closer to my request